Why the content is shrinking after adding display flex

I want to achieve this but getting shrinkage every time after adding the display flex, if I  remove the flex property then it will work properly. I also tried flex-shrink but it didn't work for me:

I am using flex-box for this layout. How can I achieve this design in a proper way? One condition is that I had tried table too but it didn't work as it grow and shrink according to the data and I am making a invoice of fixed width.
Here is my html code:


   * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      @page {
        size: A4;
        margin: 0.8cm;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        @bottom-right {
          content: counter(page) " / " counter(pages);
          font-size: 10px;
          color: black;
        }
      }

      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .big {
        font-size: 14px;
      }

      .section-2 {
        width: 100%;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        min-height: 15%;
      }

      p {
        font-size: 10px;
      }

      .section-2-body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .content-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .upper-left-content {
        width: 65%;
      }

      .upper-left-content-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .invoice-container {
        width: 55%;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
      }

      .invoice-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        align-items: baseline;
        line-height: 1.7;
      }

      .invoice-wrapper .invoice-title {
        white-space: nowrap;
      }

      .invoice-wrapper .invoice-value {
        margin-left: 10px;
      }

      .branch-section {
        width: 25%;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .branch-ref-section {
        width: 20%;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .branch-section-wrapper,
      .branch-ref-wrapper {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .branch,
      .branch-ref {
        min-height: 70px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      }

      .pos,
      .nop {
        min-height: 30px;
      }

      .lower-left-content {
        width: 65%;
      }

      .lower-left-content-wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
      }

      .lower-left-content-wrapper .buyer {
        padding: 4px;
        line-height: 1.5;
      }

      .state-info,
      .pan-info {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .upper-right-content {
        width: 35%;
      }

      .upper-right-content-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .upper-right-content-wrapper .right-side-qr-code {
        width: 55%;
      }

      .upper-right-content-wrapper .left-side-qr-code {
        width: 45%;
      }

      .upper-right-content-wrapper .qr-code img,
      .upper-right-content-wrapper .left-side-qr-code img {
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
      }

      div,
      section,
      p {
        word-break: break-all;
      }
<div class="section-2">
      <div class="section-2-body">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
          <div class="upper-wrapper">
            <div class="upper-left-content">
              <div class="upper-left-content-wrapper">
                <div class="invoice-container">
                  <div class="invoice-wrapper">
                    <div class="invoice-title">
                      <p><strong>Invoice no</strong></p>
                      <p><strong>Invoice Date</strong></p>
                      <p><strong>Payment Terms</strong></p>
                      <p><strong>Due date</strong></p>
                      <p><strong>Broker name</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="invoice-value">
                      <p><strong>:SREI2425-01871</strong></p>
                      <p>:07-Jun-2024</p>
                      <p>:90 days</p>
                      <p><strong>:06-Sep-2024</strong></p>
                      <p>:Direct</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="branch-section">
                  <div class="branch-section-wrapper">
                    <div class="branch">
                      <p>
                        <strong>Branch</strong>
                        <br />
                        <span
                          >Ginza Industries Limited (KDC) Ginza Industries
                          Limited (KDC)
                        </span>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pos">
                      <p>
                        <strong>Place of Supply:</strong>
                        <br />
                        <span>Dadra and Nagar Haveli and Daman and Diu</span>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="branch-ref-section">
                  <div class="branch-ref-wrapper">
                    <div class="branch-ref">
                      <p>
                        <strong>Branch Ref:</strong>
                        <br />
                        <span>1</span>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nop">
                      <p>
                        <strong>No of Parcel:</strong>
                        <br />
                        <span>8</span>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="lower-left-content">
              <div class="lower-left-content-wrapper">
                <div class="buyer">
                  <p>
                    <strong
                      >Buyer:
                      <span class="big"> B.K. Enterprises (Delhi)</span></strong
                    >
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <strong>Address:</strong>
                    <span>
                      2009, 1st Floor,, Kinari Bazar, Delhi., New Delhi- 110006
                    </span>
                  </p>

                  <div class="state-info">
                    <p><strong>State:</strong> <span>Delhi</span></p>
                    <p><strong>State code:</strong> <span>07</span></p>
                    <p><strong>Phone no :</strong> <span>9311142406</span></p>
                  </div>

                  <div class="pan-info">
                    <p><strong>PAN:</strong> <span>ABFPN3214M</span></p>
                    <p><strong>GST No:</strong> <span>07ABFPN3214M1ZM</span></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="upper-right-content">
            <div class="upper-right-content-wrapper">
              <div class="right-side-qr-code">
                <div class="qr-code" style="border: 1px solid red">
                  <img
                    src="https://cdn.britannica.com/17/155017-050-9AC96FC8/Example-QR-code.jpg"
                    alt=""
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="bill-no"></div>
                <div class="bill-date"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="left-side-qr-code" style="border: 1px solid blue">
                <img
                  src="https://cdn.britannica.com/17/155017-050-9AC96FC8/Example-QR-code.jpg"
                  alt=""
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>





How can I achieve this design in a proper way?

As with almost everything in code the "proper way" is highly debatable. However, I would strongly advise you to use display: grid to build this layout. You are creating a 2 dimensional layout and that is precisely what grid allows you to do. You can find out more about grid on MDN.
Whilst your design can be built using flex, flex is for one dimensional layouts and so not the ideal solution for your use case. Read more about flex on MDN.
You were right to abandon using a <table> to build this. A <table> is not really for layout... it is to display tabular data. More information about tables can be found on MDN.
To get you going this link will take you to a rough approximation of the first screenshot you provided that I have built on Codepen. Hopefully it will be enough to get you started. The code in Codepen is also shown below (n.b. I have used your html but removed unnecessary parts and updated class names. Also note my comment r.e. table usage):
<div class="invoice">
    <div class="invoice__block invoice__details">
    <!-- I would advise making the following text a <table> rather than a collection of <p> -->
        <p><strong>Invoice no</strong></p>
        <p><strong>Invoice Date</strong></p>
        <p><strong>Payment Terms</strong></p>
        <p><strong>Due date</strong></p>
        <p><strong>Broker name</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="invoice__block invoice__branch-name">
        <p>
            <strong>Branch</strong>
            <br />
            <span>Ginza Industries Limited (KDC) Ginza Industries
                Limited (KDC)
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="invoice__block invoice__branch-ref">
        <p>
            <strong>Branch Ref:</strong>
            <br />
            <span>1</span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="invoice__block invoice__qr-holder">
        <img class="invoice__qr" src="https://cdn.britannica.com/17/155017-050-9AC96FC8/Example-QR-code.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="invoice__block invoice__supply">
        <p>
            <strong>Place of Supply:</strong>
            <br />
            <span>Dadra and Nagar Haveli and Daman and Diu</span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="invoice__block invoice__parcel-count">
        <p>
            <strong>No of Parcel:</strong>
            <br />
            <span>8</span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="invoice__block invoice__label">
        Label
    </div>
    <div class="invoice__block invoice__bill-number">
        <p>
            <strong>Bill no:</strong>
            <br />
            <span>123456</span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="invoice__block invoice__bill-date">
        <p>
            <strong>Bill date:</strong>
            <br />
            <span>7th June 2024</span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="invoice__block invoice__buyer-details">
        <div class="buyer">
            <p>
                <strong>Buyer:
                    <span class="big"> B.K. Enterprises (Delhi)</span></strong>
            </p>
            <p>
                <strong>Address:</strong>
                <span>
                    2009, 1st Floor,, Kinari Bazar, Delhi., New Delhi- 110006
                </span>
            </p>

            <div class="state-info">
                <p><strong>State:</strong> <span>Delhi</span></p>
                <p><strong>State code:</strong> <span>07</span></p>
                <p><strong>Phone no :</strong> <span>9311142406</span></p>
            </div>

            <div class="pan-info">
                <p><strong>PAN:</strong> <span>ABFPN3214M</span></p>
                <p><strong>GST No:</strong> <span>07ABFPN3214M1ZM</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="invoice__block invoice__irn">
        <p>
            <strong>IRN:</strong>
            <br />
            <span>87654321</span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="invoice__block invoice__ack-date">
        <p>
            <strong>Ack date:</strong>
            <br />
            <span>7th June 2024</span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="invoice__block invoice__ack-number">
        <p>
            <strong>Ack number:</strong>
            <br />
            <span>123</span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

The styling is written in SCSS but there is no reason not to convert this to CSS should you wish.
.invoice {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 4fr 2fr 1fr 2fr 2fr;
    border: 1px solid black;

    &__block {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    &__details {
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 1 / span 3;
    }

    &__branch-name {
        grid-column: 2;
        grid-row: 1;
    }

    &__branch-ref {
        grid-column: 3;
        grid-row: 1;
    }

    &__qr-holder {
        grid-column: 4;
        grid-row: 1 / span 2;
    }

    &__qr {
        max-width: 100px;
        display: block;
        margin-inline: auto;
    }

    &__supply {
        grid-column: 2;
        grid-row: 2 / span 2;
    }

    &__parcel-count {
        grid-column: 3;
        grid-row: 2 / span 2;
    }

    &__label {
        grid-column: 5;
        grid-row: 1 / span 4;
    }

    &__bill-number {
        grid-column: 4;
        grid-row: 3;
    }

    &__bill-date {
        grid-column: 4;
        grid-row: 4;
    }

    &__buyer-details {
        grid-column: 1 / span 3;
        grid-row: 4 / span 3;
    }

    &__irn {
        grid-column: 4 / span 2;
        grid-row: 5;
    }

    &__ack-date {
        grid-column: 4;
        grid-row: 6;
    }

    &__ack-number {
        grid-column: 5;
        grid-row: 6;
    }
}


so it can't be fixed using flexbox?

This is a great answer and I'm not sure why it was downvoted initially.  I went ahead and gave it +1. My best guess is someone didn't like the SCSS variables, which to be fair, is kind of the opposite of a minimal reproducible code example unless the question used SCSS variables initially. Not sure if that was why, just speculating.

As explained in my answer, flex is for one dimensional layouts which is not what your design is. You can build your design in a huge number of ways including a table and using flex – the two methods you already tried – but you should use the right tool for the job and that tool is grid.
